# .htaccess rule to drop the connection without any response

Tags: .htaccess, connection, rule

I'm trying to set up an .htaccess rule, that, upon a certain file being requested off the server, will completely drop the connection if the rewrite condition is met.

I don't wanna just deny the connection and send any HTTP status code in response - I want to set it up in such a way that the connection will simply be dropped with no response whatsoever when the condition is met. No 403s, no redirects, nothing. Pretty much as if the request is blocked by a firewall.

How would I go about doing that, and is it doable with .htaccess?

Comment: You can try to redirect it to a specific port, then block that port on your firewall. The .htaccess part would be something like this: `RewriteRule ^certain_file.php(.*)$ http://www.example.com:5678 [L,NC]`

Comment: Won't that generate a redirect status code in response? I don't want that. Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: I don't think it would send any response code in this case. The RewriteRule would jump in just before the file would be executed, and rewrite it to the new URL, which would be blocked on the firewall. I guess you can just give it a try, and see if you can see any response codes, but I doubt it.

Comment: It will surely send a 302 status code as it redirects the user to the new location. The main idea here is to be able to drop the connection on a shared hosting, where I have no access to setting up firewall rules - otherwise I'd just block what I need to on the firewall itself, before it even reaches Apache.

Comment: was any solution or workaround found "to be able to drop the connection on a shared hosting"?

Answer (score 0):

You may do so, after one status (you may manipulate its number) provided to the client, and then use fail2ban with a jail for a long period having blockaction being set to drop. Fail2ban would add the blocked ip to the firewall iptable.